# Call a scripts libs on a specific page in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework, ionic3

I´m using an openpay library for my project. In the **Index.html** file I'm calling the scripts and it's working correctly. My problem is that I need to call them on a specific page, because a unique it loads from the beginning of the app, when I start the page in which I need exec the functions of openpay, it does not work.

I need to find the way to call the libs and execute the functions in a page which is not the root page.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For future reference, don't post your code in pictures please. Use the `{ }` button instead for markup.

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting, I consider this.

Comment: Antonio, como tip. NO uses jQuery en applicaciones que llevan Angular. Es bad practice. Angular se invento para remplazar jQuery. Otra cosa nunca uses esos links para los cdn. usa NPM. aqui te dejo el npm de openpay https://www.npmjs.com/package/openpay

Comment: "because a unique it loads" a unique what? please be more clear on what unique is